# Integrating Eventbrite with Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine, eventbrite

Has anyone has done Eventbrite integration with an Expression Engine site?  We'd like to set up events with Eventbrite and have them handle all ticket management.  But we'd like to be able to display the events within the Expression Engine site and then enable users to click on the link to be redirected to Eventbrite.  I've viewed the API and it looks like we can create custom EE pages with the API.

More importantly I'd like to let users search for events from our main site.

Has anyone done this type of work and have any hints or resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Todd Perkins got started on a module for this some time ago, but there hasn't been any action on it since then. Could be a good starting point for you though.

https://github.com/toddperkins/eventbrite

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite has a great [PHP-based API client library](http://eventbrite.github.com/#libraries) that should be able cover all of your API interaction needs.

These PHP examples might be useful as well:

- https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/tree/master/examples
- http://eventbrite.github.com/#examples

Please let [@EventbriteAPI](http://twitter.com/EventbriteAPI) know if you make any major progress on this project.  I'm sure they would love to add an Expression Engine integration to their [open source projects list](http://eventbrite.github.com/#projects) and [application showcase](http://appstores.eventbrite.com/)!